# Using Regex in PHP XPath->evaluate

Tags: php, regex, dom, xpath

As a simple example I'm trying to get all the dom objects that contain email addresses.

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML($page);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(0);
    $query = "//text()[fn:matches(., '[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}')]"; // 
    $entries = $xpath->evaluate($query, $body); // 
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        echo "Found {$entry->textContent}<br>\n";
    }
```

I'm getting the error: `"DOMXPath::evaluate() [domxpath.evaluate]: xmlXPathCompOpEval: function matches bound to undefined prefix fn ..."`

I've also tried the approach

```
//text()[
    php:function('BooleanPregMatch', '[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}', .)
]
```

without success.

I haven't been able to find many examples related to fn:match or php:function. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: can I suggest trying it with double quotes within the matches() function?

Comment: Have you read the [`DOMXPath::registerPhpFunctions()` page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`fn:matches`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) is XPath 2.0, in DOMXPath, you have XPath 1.0. That's why it doesn't work, it's not supported.

Examples for `php:function` are available on the manual page for [`DOMXPath::registerPhpFunctions`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php). You need to have PHP 5.3 to register functions.