# Get hrefs that match regex expression using PHP & XPath

Tags: php, regex, xpath, href

I have a page that contains several hyperlinks. The ones I want to get are of the format:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="diva">
<a href="/123" >text2</a>
</div>

<div id="divb">
<a href="/345" >text1</a>
<a href="/678" >text2</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to extract the three hrefs 123,345,and 678.

I know how to get all the hyperlinks using `$gm = $xpath->query("//a")` and then loop through them to get the href attribute.

Is there some sort of regexp to get the attributes with the above format only (.i.e "/digits")?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath 1.0, which is the version supported by `DOMXPath()`, has no Regex functionalities. Though, you can easily write your own PHP function to execute Regex expression to be called from `DOMXPath` if you need one, as mentioned in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031377/using-regex-in-php-xpath-evaluate).

There is XPath 1.0 way to [test if an attribute value is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854345/xpath-test-if-is-number), which you can use on `href` attribute value after `/` character, to test if the attribute value follows the pattern `/digits` :

```
//a[number(substring-after(@href,'/')) = substring-after(@href,'/')]
```

**UPDATE :**

For the sake of completeness, here is [a working example](https://eval.in/522532) of calling PHP function `preg_match` from `DOMXPath::query()` to accomplish the same task :

```
$raw_data = <<<XML
<html>
<body>

<div id="diva">
<a href="/123" >text2</a>
</div>

<div id="divb">
<a href="/345" >text1</a>
<a href="/678" >text2</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
XML;
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($raw_data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions("preg_match");

// php:function's parameters below are :
// parameter 1: PHP function name
// parameter 2: PHP function's 1st parameter, the pattern
// parameter 3: PHP function's 2nd parameter, the string
$gm = $xpath->query("//a[php:function('preg_match', '~^/\d+$~', string(@href))]");

foreach ($gm as $a) {
    echo $a->getAttribute("href") . "\n";
}
```

Comment: 1+; Too bad `//a[matches(@href, '^/\d+$')]` isn't supported.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you.

Is Xpath2.0 not supported in PHP?

Comment: @fractal5 Not by core PHP. I don't use PHP regularly, maybe there is a library that provides XPath 2.0 support, not sure. Your better bet might be to call PHP functions like `preg_match` or your own PHP function. Example provided in **UPDATE** section.