# XPath Expression: Optional character?

Tags: dom, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I would like to find:

```
<div style="text-align:center;" >
<div style="text-align: center;" >
<div style="text-align:center" >
<div style="text-align: center" >
```

So an optional space before *center* and an optional semicolon at the end.

I can do:

```
//div[@style=’text-align:center;’ or @style=’text-align: center;’ or @style=’text-align:center’ or @style=’text-align: center’]
```

But is there a “cleaner” way? And able to take many more optional characters without getting too long?

Comment: Presumably you're in XPath 1.0, otherwise you would just be using matches()? But if you need an XPath 1.0 solution, *please say so*!

Comment: @MichaelKay I don't know, Im using PHP 5.6.23 and I plan to upgrade to 7 soon. The only thing I see is: DOM/XML API Version  20031129, libxml Version  2.9.4, HTML Support  enabled, XPath Support  enabled.

Comment: That's version 1.0. Sadly the XML libraries in PHP haven't kept up with the latest standards. We're trying to correct that by providing Saxon/C with a PHP interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can first remove the optional characters f.e space and semicolon, assuming they aren't used in the required text, using [`translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) function, and then check whether the result equals only the required text f.e 'text-align:center' :

```
//div[translate(@style, ' ;', '') = 'text-align:center']
```

Or, when the pattern gets more complex, you can use regex in your XPath via PHP [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)  :

```
$xp->query("//div[php:function('preg_match', '~text-align:\s*center;*~', string(@style))]");
```

See full example demonstrating how to call PHP function from XPath in my older post : [Get hrefs that match regex expression using PHP & XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35532854/2998271).